# Invalid keystore format(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

How to solve the problem in Android Studio 2023.3?
My jdk version is 1.8

```
Execution failed for task ':client:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key base from store "D:\WorkFile\passcheck\_sign\_sign_qskj\my.jks": Invalid keystore format
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I hope someone can help me take a look.

Comment: Ok. i hava solve this problem when i use jdk1.8.0-361。   
Yesterday, i use jdk 1.8.0-202 or jdk 1.8.0-151， failed.
jdk 17 or jdk 21 failed.

I read the ORACLE release notes about jdk 1.8, some characterastic of  encryption algorithm and encryption certificate were updated when ORACLE updating frenquent release.

In the end, Use the jdk 1.8 version should than jdk1.8.0-300